# UITableViewCells reorder when not visible on screen

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a problem and lots of difficulty finding a solution, even if I would assume lots of people should have had similar issues. Hopefully someone can help me.

I've created a Settings screen for my application using a UITableView. A NSArray is used to configure the controls I intend to display. The array looks like this:

```
[self setControlArray:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                 [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Username", @"text", nil], 
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Password", @"text", nil], 
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Server", @"text", nil], 
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Port", @"text", nil], 
                  [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"Use SSL", @"text", nil], 
                  nil],
                 nil]];
```

For every item in the array I create a control in the following manner (in ViewDidLoad):

```
// TextField: USERNAME
username = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(99.0, 15.0, 190.0, 18.0)];
[self layoutTextField:username withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:13.0] keyboardType:UIKeyboardTypeAlphabet placeholder:@"Username" clearsOnBeginEditing:NO];
[username setText:[Settings sipUser]];
```

Finally every control is added to the UITableView using the [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath] message:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    NSString *label = [[[controlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:label];

    // TextField: USERNAME
    if ([[[[controlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"] isEqual:@"Username"]) {
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:username];
}
return cell;
```

Every time one of the controls in my array gets out of focus (disappears from screen) because of the scrolling the controls that were out of sight get reordered. I would assume the controls are released and recreated when scrolling back in sight, but whatever I try I can't find a solution for this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is, you're using `[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier]` which can actually return a non-nil cell (e.g. with one of the other buttons) and then you'll just return it, making it seem they're rearranging (almost) randomly.

You have to make an `else` branch in the code and, if the dequeued reusable cell isn't nil:

- remove any buttons from the cell
- add the button you need
- set the cell's label

and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks mate, your suggestion worked for me. For any people interested my [tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:] message looks like the following now:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

    NSString *label = [[[controlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:label];

    // TextField: USERNAME
    if ([[[[controlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"] isEqual:@"Username"]) {
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:username];
    }
} else {
    NSString *label = [[[controlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"];
    [[cell textLabel] setText:label];

    // TextField: USERNAME
    if ([[[[controlArray objectAtIndex:[indexPath section]] objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]] objectForKey:@"text"] isEqual:@"Username"]) {
        [username removeFromSuperview];
        [[cell contentView] addSubview:username];
    }
}  
return cell;
```